# How to store json.stringify response into a file?

Tags: json, node.js, ibm-watson

Currently I am having problem with node.js project that I am doing right now, but I don't know how can I store json.stringify response that I get from the below code in a file from where I can access jSON data or is there a better way to do this without it storing in file.

Here is my code:

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');

var personality_insights = watson.personality_insights({
    username: '...',
    password: '...',
    version: 'v2'
});

personality_insights.profile({
    text: 'I write this to explain why I’ll be holding back my album, 1989, from the new streaming service, Apple Music. I feel this deserves an explanation because Apple has been and will continue to be one of my best partners in selling music and creating ways for me to connect with my fans. I respect the company and the truly ingenious minds that have created a legacy based on innovation and pushing the right boundaries.I’m sure you are aware that Apple Music will be offering a free 3 month trial to anyone who signs up for the service. I’m not sure you know that Apple Music will not be paying writers, producers, or artists for those three months. I find it to be shocking, disappointing, and completely unlike this historically progressive and generous company.This is not about me. Thankfully I am on my fifth album and can support myself, my band, crew, and entire management team by playing live shows. This is about the new artist or band that has just released their first single and will not be paid for its success.',
    language: 'en' 
}, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error:', err);
        } else {
            console.log( JSON.stringify(response, null, 2) );
        }
    });
});
```

I am using watson developer cloud above in my code.

Comment: Can you explain why do want to store the response in a file?

Comment: I order to access it to show on hosted server or is there any another way to do it @Tomalak ?

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? Something like "I need them a few lines later in my code"?

Comment: yes something like that

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call - You need to use the callback function, that's what it is for. Instead of `JSON.stringify(response)`, just call `doSomeWork(response)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
var fs = require('fs');

var personality_insights = watson.personality_insights({
    username: '...',
    password: '...',
    version: 'v2'
});

personality_insights.profile({
    text: 'blah blah blah',
    language: 'en' 
}, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error:', err);
        } else {
            fs.writeFile(
                './file.json', 
                JSON.stringify(response, null, 2), 
                function(err){
                    throw err;
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```